# Defining function within a function in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are nested functions a bad thing in gcc ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929281/are-nested-functions-a-bad-thing-in-gcc)

As far as I know, C does not allow a function to be defined within other function. But the following code compiles and runs without any error in gcc. Can someone explain the reason why? See this also : http://ideone.com/AazVK

```
#include <stdio.h>

void val1( int x ) 
{
        void sig( int x ) {
                printf("%d\n",x*10);
        }
        sig(x);
}

int main()
{       
        void val2(int x) {
                x = x*10;
                val1(x);

                printf( "%d\n", x ); 
                if ( x < 10000 ) {
                        val2(x);                
                }
        }

        val2(20);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929281/are-nested-functions-a-bad-thing-in-gcc

Comment: add the `-pedantic` flag to enable standards mode, and you'll get warnings when using gnu extensions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`gcc` (but not `g++`) supports [nested functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) as a [C language extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions).