# Nested Functions on Android NDK

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, nested-function

Is there a way to use nested functions on the the Android NDK? It should be possible, since the NDK uses gcc right?

Well I tried defining a function inside main, and the compiler simply doesn't recognize it.
Here's the error

error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
error: expected '}' at end of input

Comment: Question is not clear. Please mention clearly what are you trying to do and also put the logs if it is failing.

Comment: what have you tried already? Have you tried any sample projects from the NDK? should be relatively easy to take some code in a method or even main() from a sample project and nest it to see what happens...

Comment: Please have a look at this thread as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929281/are-nested-functions-a-bad-thing-in-gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly. But as far as NDK uses `arm` gcc compiler and that nested functions may be broken on [ARM architecture](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2000-09/msg00353.html) - my best guess is that nested functions may be disabled in NDK toolset. In any way - nested functions is GCC extension, so if you want your code to be portable you better don't use gcc extensions at all and use C89/C90 compatible code instead.

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, I replaced them with functors.

Answer (score 1):

The nested functions example from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html), where a `foo()` contains a `square()`, compiles and runs fine (on a Tegra 3). I use the NDK r8 android toolchain (with android-cmake, if that makes any difference, which shouldn't be the case). Maybe you should try with r8 in case you use an older version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. You may need to add the -fnested-functions flag to gcc calls.

Comment: I tried adding -fnested-functions to LOCAL_CFLAGS, but the compiler doesn't seem to recognize this flag. Spits out error: unrecognized command line option "-fnested-functions"

Answer (score 0):

Nested functions require an executable stack, which is disabled by default in Android.

It took me an unbelievable amount of time to figure it out - but you need to add the following to your CFLAGS:

-z execstack -Wa,--execstack

All the best!