# Is nested function in GCC safe now? Class definition in GNU C

Tags: c, oop, gcc, nested-function

Before, the use of nested function in GCC is [controversial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929281/are-nested-functions-a-bad-thing-in-gcc). Its main drawback is that it uses a technique called [trampoline](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html). Now that you can prevent this by specifying [-fno-trampolines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Trampolines.html) while compiling, is it finally safe to use?

Nested functions are very interesting to me since I can use them to create a struct that is similar to a class, by defining and assigning the class function inside of the constructor function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct classStruct;
typedef struct classStruct ClassA;

struct classStruct {
    int a;
    //class constructor
    ClassA* (*new_Class_A)();
    //class destructor
    void (*free_Class_A)();
    //class function
    int (*geta)();
};

ClassA* new_Class_A(int a) {
    ClassA* temp = NULL;
    temp = (ClassA*) malloc(sizeof(ClassA));
    //assign variables
    temp->a = a;
    //assign constructor
    temp->new_Class_A = new_Class_A;
    //assign destructor
    void free_Class_A() {
        temp->new_Class_A = NULL;
        temp->free_Class_A = NULL;
        temp->geta = NULL;
        temp->a = 0;
        free(temp);
    }
    temp->free_Class_A = free_Class_A;
    //assign class function
    int geta () {
        return temp->a;
    }
    temp->geta = geta;
    return temp;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //declare a new instance
    ClassA* ANumber = new_Class_A(12);
    //access a class function is now super easy
    printf("%d\n",ANumber->geta());
    //destroy instance
    ANumber->free_Class_A();
    return 0;
}
```

Then I can now call the class function object->geta() just like I do in C++ instead of object->geta(&object), effectively having something similar to an implicit "this" keyword. Is this now acceptable? Will I run into trouble invoking functions outside of the constructor function?

Let's leave questions like "why?" or "why didn't you just use C++" out of this discussion for now :P.

Comment: Nested functions are a gcc extension.  They are not part of standard C.  Specify the `-pedantic` option to gcc to see any ISO C violations (like nested functions).

Comment: Hi Tom, yes I'm aware of that and that's why I specify GNU C instead of ANSI C :)

Comment: I think your use of `geta` invokes undefined behavior.  You're storing a pointer to `geta` in a struct, then returning a pointer to that struct.  At that point, `temp->geta` may not be invoked, since the containing function has returned.  Remember, C (including gcc) does not support closures.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that's what I was worried about too. In this case it does work but I may just be lucky. What a bummer, I really wanted this to work. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you're just lucky, since `geta` references `temp` which is no longer accessible to it.

Comment: Strongly suggest: follow the c language standard and DO NOT make use of gcc 'extensions'.   Such usage will 'bite' you in the end and you learn nothing useful.

Comment: I would try something like `ClassA* getThis(void) { return temp; }` as nested function, and look at the address returned. If it matches the address of the object, I would investigate the assembly to see *how it is done*. If it does not match, I would be sure that it does not work.

Comment: Oh, just tried that. The nested function always returns the *same* pointer, I needed to create more than 1 object to see this. -- Conclusion: If you want OOP in C, follow the standard, and use a visible `this` on every member function.

Comment: Simply move to C++ if you want classes. Any attempt for classes in C won't work, unless you can pass first parameter of each function actual struct pointer. Period. End of story.

Comment: Various languages supports nested functions (and so also good techniques to support them). GCC supports various languages with nested functions (D, Fortran, ADA), so... support (and stable support) is in the GCC code. Stable, but not portable [in case of C]

Comment: From your link: "For languages other than Ada, the -ftrampolines and -fno-trampolines options currently have no effect"

Answer (score 2):

I'm partly responsible for pushing for `-fno-trampolines` in GCC.

Unless the current implementation changed, what `-fno-trampolines` does is completely prevent the generation of trampolines. Thus erroring out on any code that would require an executable stack to work.

So, no, it doesn't "fix" nested functions, it makes them non-compilable instead of allowing that dangerous hack.

If you need something like this, by all means use a better language like C++, or have a look at asterisk: they use an alternate technique that does compile safely with clang.

Comment: In fact, it looks like with current gcc, when you use `-fno-trampolines` for code with a nested function that would normally need a trampoline, the result is... that it uses a trampoline anyway.  Oops.  https://godbolt.org/z/K1Ex4Y4Ya

Answer (score 0):

> Now that you can prevent this by specifying -fno-trampolines while compiling

Not true.  The [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options) says:

> For languages other than Ada, the -ftrampolines and -fno-trampolines options currently have no effect, and trampolines are always generated on platforms that need them for nested functions.

So if you have a GNU C program that uses nested functions, and you pass around pointers to them in a manner that normally needs a trampoline, and you build it with `-fno-trampolines`, the result is... that the compiler emits a trampoline anyway.  Example: https://godbolt.org/z/aEnP7ebMT

And it appears that it will also set up the `.note.GNU-stack` section so as to create an executable that requests an executable stack, with all the issues that raises.  So if you were thinking "Oh, if it were actually trying to execute code on the stack on a modern system, it would just crash", think again.

On my system at least the linker gives a warning about this.

---

Also, just to emphasize comments for other people reading this: **the code in the question is totally broken**.  It's written as if defining the `geta` inner function which uses `temp->a` makes a copy of the value of `temp->a` in some place where it can be used later.  That's not correct.  `geta` runs on the same stack frame as its parent `new_Class_A`; the only data copied into the trampoline is the address of the code for the child function, and a pointer to the parent's stack frame.  The value of `temp->` is NOT copied, so the value you're accessing with `temp->a` involves loading the actual `temp` variable on the parent function's stack, then dereferencing it.  So:

- if the parent function modifies the value of `temp` or of `temp->a` before the callback to `geta` is used again, the callback will see the *new* value.
- if the parent function returns before the callback to `geta` is used again - which is exactly how the OP's code intends to produce its desired effect! - then `geta` will use a stack frame that no longer exists.  Very likely, the space formerly used for `temp` now contains garbage, so the callback will load from a random address and crash, or worse.

OP seems not to have read all the way through the gcc documentation they themselves linked, which says clearly:

> If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose.